# Looking for third party CMS to integrate with an MVC site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, cloud, document, lucene.net

I am looking at the posibility of integrating a third party component into our MVC-based site. We have an MVC-based portal that is hosted in the cloud and need document handling and search features without taking the full job of implementing it from scratch.

Is there any other third party systems that are cloud compatible and provide an API for handling documents, security and full text search?

Comment: Does Lucene.Net not fit the bill? Or building on top of that would be considered from scratch?

Comment: Setting up Lucene is both expencive and limited when it comes to file content support. At least too expencive and limited compared to the cost of setting it up. I'm looking for a third party system that can provide me document management, integrated user handling and search features.

Comment: SO is not a product recommendation service.

Comment: Thanks for that assessment L.B, but I did expect the users to be able to exchange experiences and advice. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 6):

[Orchard](http://www.orchardproject.net/) is a free, open source, community-focused project aimed at delivering applications and reusable components on the ASP.NET platform.

> In the near term, the Orchard project is focused on delivering a
>   **.NET-based CMS application** that will allow users to rapidly create content-driven Websites, and an extensibility framework that will
>   allow developers and customizers to provide additional functionality
>   through module extensions and themes.

It is built using of [ASP.NET MVC as a foundation](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/How-Orchard-works)

It can run in the cloud: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Deploying-Orchard-to-Windows-Azure

It can do [text search](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Search-and-indexing).

Comment: I also think the best opportunity for an Mvc Website is Orchard

Comment: Orchard CMS is built with ASP.NET MVC 3 at the moment and just hours ago version 1.5 got released. The dedication this project sees from its (core) developer community is great and the forums has a high and good answer rate.

Comment: Well, it looks as the closest thing available. I'll have a closer look.

Comment: The dynamic nature of Orchard is also it's weakness. We've experienced some real performance issues with Orchard. Would recommend that you do some research if it will be cause any trouble before you choose it.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). Solr adds some incredible support on top of Lucene (java). I know it seems as though you want a .net solution, however I will say that solr has a fantastic HTTP interface, so you can easily connect it via services.

Comment: Solr would only provide a piece in the puzzle. It will only provide me with a search engine - nothing more.